# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'combineReducers' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

I'm trying to run the storeApp which is in the egghead.io using npm.
 when i run the app it says I'm getting the error.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'combineReducers' of undefined
webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: {
        path: './',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        port: 2220
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "redux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.7.6",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "react": "^0.14.8",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.2",
    "webpack": "^1.12.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

```js
/*
 * We will be explaining the code below
 * in the following lessons. For now,
 * feel free to click around and notice
 * how the current state tree is logged
 * to the console on every change.
 */

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Redux from 'redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO';
const TOGGLE_TODO = 'TOGGLE_TODO';
const SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER = 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER';

const Filters = {
    SHOW_ALL: 'SHOW_ALL',
    SHOW_COMPLETED: 'SHOW_COMPLETED',
    SHOW_ACTIVE: 'SHOW_ACTIVE'
};

/*
 * Components
 */

class AddTodo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <input type='text' ref='input' />
            <button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)}>
        Add
        </button>
        </div>
    );
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        const node = this.refs.input;
        const text = node.value.trim();
        this.props.onAddClick(text);
        node.value = '';
    }
}

const FilterLink = ({ isActive, name, onClick }) => {
    if (isActive) {
        return <span>{name}</span>;
    }

    return (
        <a href='#' onClick={e => { e.preventDefault(); onClick(); }}>
    {name}
</a>
);
};

const Footer = ({ filter, onFilterChange }) => (
<p>
Show:
{' '}
<FilterLink
name='All'
isActive={filter === Filters.SHOW_ALL}
onClick={() => onFilterChange(Filters.SHOW_ALL)} />
{', '}
<FilterLink
name='Completed'
isActive={filter === Filters.SHOW_COMPLETED}
onClick={() => onFilterChange(Filters.SHOW_COMPLETED)} />
{', '}
<FilterLink
name='Active'
isActive={filter === Filters.SHOW_ACTIVE}
onClick={() => onFilterChange(Filters.SHOW_ACTIVE)} />
</p>
);

const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => (
<li
onClick={onClick}
style={{
    textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none',
        cursor: 'pointer'
}}>
{text}
</li>
);


const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => (
<ul>
{todos.map(todo =>
<Todo {...todo}
key={todo.id}
onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)} />
)}
</ul>
);

let nextTodoId = 0;
const TodoApp = ({ dispatch, todos, visibilityFilter }) => {
    let visibleTodos = todos;

    switch (visibilityFilter) {
        case Filters.SHOW_COMPLETED:
            visibleTodos = todos.filter(todo => todo.completed);
            break;
        case Filters.SHOW_ACTIVE:
            visibleTodos = todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
            break;
    }

    return (
        <div>
        <AddTodo
    onAddClick={text =>
    dispatch({ type: ADD_TODO, text, id: nextTodoId++ })
} />
<TodoList
    todos={visibleTodos}
    onTodoClick={id =>
    dispatch({ type: TOGGLE_TODO, id })
} />
<Footer
    filter={visibilityFilter}
    onFilterChange={filter =>
    dispatch({ type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER, filter })
} />
</div>
);
};

/*
 * Reducers
 */

const visibilityFilter = (state = Filters.SHOW_ALL, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
            return action.filter;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO:
            return [...state, {
                text: action.text,
                id: action.id,
                completed: false
            }];
        case TOGGLE_TODO:
            return state.map(todo =>
            todo.id === action.id ?
                Object.assign({}, todo, { completed: !todo.completed }) :
                todo
        );
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const todoApp = Redux.combineReducers({
    visibilityFilter,
    todos
});

/*
 * Go!
 */

const store = Redux.createStore(todoApp);
const dispatch = (action) => {
    store.dispatch(action);
    console.log('----------------');
    console.log('current state:');
    console.log(store.getState());
}
const render = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
    <TodoApp
    {...store.getState()}
    dispatch={dispatch}
        />,
        document.getElementById('root')
);
}
render();
store.subscribe(render);
console.log('current state:');
console.log(store.getState());

// noprotect
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="root">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the *redux* package as well. Add to your *package.json*

```
npm install --save-dev redux
```

**Note:** your application name is also *redux* so npm will throw an error at you when installing.

**Tip:** Also I would recommend you install all dependecies with the *--save-dev* option. This is to optimize the size of your bundle when building for production so *webpack* will only include the necessary components, not whole libraries.

Comment: No, I have installed the redux maybe since my project name is redux its not showing up.

I resolved this issue by changing the import to import Redux, { createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';

and changed the reference of index.js in index.html at the end before the body(this is because maybe the DOM was not built so if we refer at the bottom it was working fine).