# How to import redux to angularjs 1.x app?

Tags: angularjs, redux

I was trying to use redux in an angular 1.x app. I added the scripts

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-redux/umd/ng-redux.min.js"></script>
```

to my html head. Then I created a file just to test if things are working correctly:

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRedux"]).config(function ($ngReduxProvider) {
  $ngReduxProvider.createStoreWith(
    {
      counterStateReducer: function (state, action) {},
    },
    []
  );
});
```

But when I run I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'combineReducers')
    at Object.$get (ngRedux.js:92:18)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:5208:19)
...(other lines ommited by me)
```

I know that the error is from the file `ngRedux.js` specifically at this line `_reducer = combineReducers(reducersObj);` but I am new to JS and the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-redux) don't say how to import this library other than by adding the scripts, so how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545920/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-combinereducers-of-undefined?

Comment: @AasthaBist yes i tried installing the scripts in the project folder but that didn;t work as well, same error. And I also added the redux library but nothing changed. seems like something with the syntax not being recognized because I also got sometimes that `require is not defined`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603514/javascript-require-function-giving-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined - Is this related to your error?

Comment: it would be weird if it is the cause of the error, as ngRedux and redux (should?) be loaded in the angular app like any other scripts, so why would they contain code that's not compatible to run in a browser? My question is how can I properly import redux and ngRedux to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the dependencies scripts were wrong, these ones worked for me:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.js"></script>
<!-- Redux -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/redux@latest/dist/redux.js"></script>
<!-- NgRedux -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ng-redux/umd/ng-redux.js"></script>
```

I got them from the examples page on the official github repos of [ngRedux](https://github.com/angular-redux/ng-redux/tree/master/examples/counter) and [redux](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter-vanilla).

Note: you may also need to declare `type=module` on these scripts if you get that `import` is not defined.